# Discrete to Continuous Sinc Filter.

Tags: interpolation

I'd like to know, how to implement a curve interpolator using only past and current data samples. The goal is to get a smooth curve out of discrete samples that're fed in real-time.

To this end, I discovered the Sinc interpolation and filter, and I think they fit my purpose. However, when I put it into JavaScript, I don't quite seem to get it right.

Put it simply, I want to ask, how do I get a continuous-time sample $y(t)$ from a set of past samples $x(i)$ where $i$ corresponds to the most recent sample, $i-1$ to one in the past, and $i-2$ so on. It is assumed that $i+1 \gt t \ge i, t \in \mathbb{R}, i \in \mathbb{N}$, and they are of the same unit (e.g. they're both measured in seconds).

Comment: I solved my own problem: $\text{sinc}$ is 2-sided, where-as real-time curve-generation require a 1-sided function for the filter. Leaving this here for others to provide different insights.